# Mutating table problem, but im using compound triggers and still the same problem

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, triggers, database-trigger

So I want to change the information of my database record that is email information, so I made a compound trigger that saves the information inside a database object then assigns to the: NEW elements
but still  have the problem of mutating elements, hope u can help me

```
create or replace TRIGGER MAIL_OUTBOX 
FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON MAIL_OUTBOX 
COMPOUND TRIGGER
TYPE mail IS RECORD
(v_Mail_Id VARCHAR2(200),
v_new_comment varchar2(200),
v_new_email varchar2(200),
v_new_cc varchar2(200),
replaced_cc  varchar2(200),
replaced_receiver varchar2(200));
objetoMail mail;

BEFORE EACH ROW IS
BEGIN

objetoMail.v_Mail_Id := :NEW.MAIL_OUTBOX_ID;
objetoMail.v_new_comment := :OLD.COMMENTS;
objetoMail.v_new_cc := :OLD.CC;
objetoMail.replaced_receiver := :OLD.RECEIVER;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(objetoMail.v_new_comment); 

IF objetoMail.v_new_comment LIKE '%ORA-29279%' THEN
SELECT regexp_substr(objetoMail.v_new_comment,'<([^>]+)>',1,1,NULL,1) into objetoMail.v_new_email                          
objetoMail.v_new_comment := 'Receptor desconocido ' || objetoMail.v_new_email;
:NEW.COMMENTS := objetoMail.v_new_comment;



hselect REGEXP_REPLACE(objetoMail.v_new_cc, objetoMail.v_new_email, 'xxx@xxxxxx.com' )
into objetoMail.replaced_cc
from  MAIL_OUTBOX; 
:NEW.CC := objetoMail.replaced_cc; 
select REGEXP_REPLACE(objetoMail.replaced_receiver, objetoMail.v_new_email, 'xxx@xxxxxx.com' )
into objetoMail.replaced_receiver
from  MAIL_OUTBOX; 
:NEW.RECEIVER := objetoMail.replaced_receiver; 

END IF;
END BEFORE EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT IS 
v_Mail_Id VARCHAR2(60);
BEGIN
MAIL_PROCESS(NULL, objetoMail.v_Mail_Id );
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
```

Comment: The cause of the mutating trigger is the select statement from MAIL_OUTBOX  in the trigger on MAIL_OUTBOX .  Do you need to select from MAIL_OUTBOX ? You are setting a variable so I think you can select from dual instead

Comment: wow man, that worked perfectly, really apreciated, you rock!